# Incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind with negative parameter

Tags: mathematica, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

Abramowitz & Stegun 17.4.18 gives the following formula for $E(u, -m)$:

$$
E(u,-m) = (1+m)^{1/2} \{E(u(1+m)^{1/2},m(m+1)^{-1}) - m(1+m)^{-1/2}   \mathrm{sn}(u(1+m)^{1/2}, m(1+m)^{-1})\; \mathrm{cd}(u(1+m)^{1/2}, m(1+m)^{-1}) \}.
$$

However, a quick Mathematica test does not seem to verify this relationship:

```
u = RandomReal[]; m = RandomReal[]; a = u Sqrt[1 + m]; b = m / (m + 1);

Sqrt[1 + m] (EllipticE[a, b] - m / Sqrt[1 + m] JacobiSN[a, b] JacobiCD[a, b])
EllipticE[u, -m]

>>> 0.136459
>>> 0.214315 + 0. I
```

Does anyone know the correct equation, or have I made an error somewhere?

Comment: Common mistake with Mathematica Elliptic functions. The first argument to EllipticE is $\phi$. So to get $E(u,m)$ you need to use $\texttt{EllipticE[JacobiAmplitude[u,m],m]}$.

Comment: @Somos, thanks for the reply. I still can't get it working, however; do you have a MWE that I could use?

Comment: Compare with [NIST 19.7.5](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E5) equation for $E(\phi,ik)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
test[u_,m_] := Module[{s, a, b}, s = Sqrt[1 + m]; a = u s; b = m/(1 + m);
{ s EllipticE[JacobiAmplitude[a, b], b] - 
    m / s JacobiSN[a, b] JacobiCD[a, b],
  EllipticE[JacobiAmplitude[u, -m], -m] }];
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you stumbled on a correction to the formula at the same time as showing me the difference between $u$ and $\phi$... The whole thing would have been multiplied by $s$ according to what's in the book, but this way actually works.